# Small World clustering coefficients and characteristic path lengths

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I want to compute and compare the clustering coefficients and characteristic path lengths of 50 WS graphs for different values of    between  0  and  1 with n and d fixed.
Here is what I have so far:

```
n, d = 1000, 5
for p in range(0,1,50):
G1 = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(n, 2*d, p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Change the while loop to a for loop if you prefer with your range(0,1,50) or np.linspace(0,1,50)

```
i = 0
results={}
while i < 1:
   current_I = []
   current_C = []
   for _ in range(20):
      G = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(n = 1000,k = 4,p = i)
      current_I.append(nx.average_shortest_path_length(G))
      current_C.append(nx.average_clustering(G))
   results[i] = (np.mean(current_I), np.mean(current_C))
   i += .052631
```

Comment: I want it to return as output the values of the clustering coefficient and characteristic path length for all 50 values of p not the mean

Comment: @Keralf2020 this is iterating 20 times for each p and returning the mean of that, not the mean of all values for p. if you want sample size of 1 for each value p just remove the nested for-loop. the results dict here will have 20 keys in either case.